# Is it possible to add a shortcut for Cmd-Enter in TinyMCE?

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

I'm using the newest version, 4.4.0, and having no trouble defining shortcuts for most keys, but can't get anything to work with a hotkey plus the Enter key:

```js
// this works great (meta = Cmd on macs)
editor.addShortcut('meta+b', 'testB', () => console.log('meta+b!')) 

// nope!
editor.addShortcut('meta+enter', 'testEnter', () => console.log('y u no work'))
```

Is this unsupported? Or is there some secret incantation? The [documentation](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/api/tinymce/tinymce.shortcuts/) is pretty sparse, and the one [forum post](http://archive.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=35513) I found is inconclusive and out of date.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work by defining a `keydown` event handler instead of using `addShortcut`:

```js
editor.on('keydown', event => {
  if (event.which === 13 && event.metaKey) {
    console.log('yay')
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `'meta+13'`? You need to use key codes for non-character keys.